# posteriori and posterior

Tags: differences, mathematics

What are the differences in meaning and usage between *posteriori* and *posterior*?

Particularly in probability, statistics and logic, when should I use which?

For example, why are "max a posteriori" and "posterior distributions"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A posteriori** is something "*relating to or denoting reasoning or knowledge that proceeds from observations or experiences to the deduction of probable causes.*"

It constrasts with **a priori** that is, instead, something "*relating to or denoting reasoning or knowledge that proceeds from theoretical deduction rather than from observation or experience.*"

The first expressions that you asked for, then, is used when you assert or state something after having observed the subject of the matter. You can read more about these two terms in [their wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori).

**Posterior** means the back part of a body, or something coming after.

---

<sup>**Note**: The emphasized parts are taken from the NOAD.</sup>

Comment: Why the -1? Since I don't see any mistakes, it would be nice to know, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Bayesian statistics, you begin with an estimated probability distribution, called the **prior** or the **prior distribution**.  Then you do your number-crunching, and come out with a (presumably) better estimate of the probability distribution, called the **posterior distribution**.

As far as I know, this is not related to the philosophical term **a posteriori**.

Comment: I would check out this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) @GEdgar.

Answer (score 3):

In philosophy and logic there is a distinction between two types of knowledge:

***a priori***

> Knowledge that is arrived at without experience.  Such as: 'All bachelors are unmarried'

and

***a posteriori***

> Knowledge that is arrived at through experience. Such as: 'Some bachelors are happy'

I'm not sure how it relates to 'max a posteriori' or 'posterior distributions', but this is a useful distinction for logic.

(examples are from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori))

Answer (score 1):

*A Posteriori* means "posterior to"; *posterior* has several meanings, but conveys the idea of "coming afterward" (thus its common use in anatomy to refer to parts of the body on the backside of a corresponding part). Knowing when to use which in various subjects requires understanding the context in which you want to use each; they are both adjectives but convey slightly different connotations.

Comment: Thanks! For example, why are "max a posteriori" and "posterior distributions"?

Comment: More specifically, 'a posteriori' is used in philosophy to describe that which is knowable from investigation about how things are in the world. It contrasts with 'a priori', which describes that which is knowable without reference to experience.

Comment: *A posteriori* doesn't mean "posterior to": it rather means "from what comes after". Similarly, *a priori* means "from what comes before".

Comment: @Cerberus: Are A posteriori  and A priori native English words?

Comment: A posteriori = posterior to = from what comes after. They are all the same. @Tim, they are Latin phrases.

Comment: @Tim the two phrases "maximum a posteriori" and "posterior distributions" refer to the same statistical theory, and are simply different ways to refer to it, just as one might refer to "a spacious room" as "a room of great capacity".

Comment: @Tim they are fixed expressions, posteriori doesn't exist alone, I think.

Comment: They are *not* "all the same". It may not be important, but you cannot translate *a posteriori* as *posterior to*. And the former is originally Latin, the latter is English.